# active admin overide form page with relation belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

i'm using gem [active admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin), and i want to override my form page. How to showing field from belongs to on my role form if i have relation like this :

model user :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role
end
```

model role :

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

how to showing all field on model user in form role in active admin?

Answer (score 0):

i'm found the answer :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Role do
    form do |f|
        f.inputs "Role Details" do
          f.input :user_id
        end

        f.inputs "User Details" do 
          f.input :email, :input_html => { :value => f.object.user.email }      
        end

        f.actions
      end
end
```